# Android: Automatically Record Video And Send Resulting Movie File To E-Mail Address When Phone Call Recieved

Tags: android, video, automation, phone-call

I am trying to determine if it is possible to use an incoming call to trigger an Android enabled phone to record video for a particular number of seconds and then send the resulting video file to an e-mail address.  Sort of like having remote control camera functionality that is activated by an incoming call.  (No particular model of phone or version of Android.  I'm first just trying to determine if this is even possible.)

Here is a scenario to help understand how I am trying to apply this:

1. Two phones are involved, Phone A & Phone B.
2. Phone A is secured to pole with the camera viewfinder facing it's subject in New York.
3. Phone B is 3,000 miles away in Portland, Oregon.
4. Phone B calls phone A.
5. On receiving the phone call (or any phone call), Phone A automatically begins recording 10 seconds of video, then sends the resulting video file to an outside e-mail address.
6. All of this is done using the regular telephone cellular network, not wi-Fi

I hope I am clear eneough.  You don't have to answer in great length.  At this point I'm mainly interested in simply knowing if this is possible, and if so, what level of difficulty and possible limitations might exist depending on things like type of Android phone.

I really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't work. I think you can have a broadcast receiver for incoming calls and then it's a matter to start video recording and then send the video to your email.
All this can be done, it's a matter of putting it together ;)

Comment: Very helpful.  Are you aware of any hardware limitations, or is the broadcast receiver feature of Android robust eneough to work accross different models?

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitations. I've used for receiving SMS and it's working on a wide range of user devices.